# Extracting and sorting data in an array?

Tags: c++, arrays

Here is my array:

```
int grid[gridsize+1] = { 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 4, 1, 5, 3, 3, 6, 2, 6, 4, 5, 5, 5, 3, 6, 2, 6, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 4, 7, 7, 8, 5, 8, 8, 8, 4, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 4, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8 };
```

Each number represents a colour, I would like to create multiple arrays for each unique number. The created arrays will store the locations of that number from the original array.

e.g

```
colour1[5]
[0]=0       //because the number 1 is stored in element 0.
[1]=1
[2]=8
[3]=9
```

The numbers in grid will change every time I run, so things need to be dynamic?
I can write inefficient code that accomplishes this, but it's just repetitive and I can't comprehend a way to turn this into something I can put in a function.

Here is what I have;

```
int target_number = 1
grid_size = 64;
int counter = -1;
int counter_2 = -1;
int colour_1;
while (counter < grid_size + 1){
   counter = counter + 1;
   if (grid[counter] == target)
       counter_2 = counter_2 + 1;
       colour_1[counter_2] = counter;
   }
}
```

I have to do this for each colour, when I try to make a function, it cannot access the main array in main so is useless.

Comment: Use a `std::vector`.

Comment: `int target_number = max_number - max_number + 1` can be simplified to `int target_number = 1` but perhaps that is a typo

Comment: @40two I'm quite the newbie, are vectors not out of my scope of skill?

Comment: If you need a dynamic array then `std::vector` is the answer. It's very easy to use no worries about that.

Comment: @CarCzar Yes I don't know why on earth I wrote that.

Comment: @user3787930 _"are vectors not out of my scope of skill?"_ Depends, I don't suppose you're just dumb. Simply check the [docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and the examples given there, and you'll find that using `std::vecor<int>` is much easier, than managing all of these allocations and stuff yourself with a `int grid[gridsize+1] ...`. IMHO using plain c-style arrays and heap or stack allocation requires a lot of more skills to do it right.

Comment: if you're a little bit daring, you could consider looking into the std algorithms to do some of the tedious work for you. The std algorithms will work on arrays like the one you have, and will also work on any std containers such as std::vector if you change your code. You would probably be most interested in std::find() for this particular problem. Also std::distance can help you to convert an iterator into an array index.

Comment: @user3787930 ;). One more thing I will mention, is don't over optimize. If you plan on having 10s of thousands of "colors" in your collection, or if you plan on performing this operation 10s of thousands of times, then perhaps you can start to think about optimizing this and seeing some meaningful gains from it. However, if you are using a list of 50 or even 5000 elements in it. The efficiency gains you will achieve are very likely going to save less running time that you will spend implementing them. That being said, there is some value in searching out this answer for academic reasons.

Comment: @CarCzar Watching a tutorial on Vectors, first thing that happened is that the size of the vector is declared! Is there any way to avoid this, I don't know how many unique numbers there are going to be.....ohh use vector for the main grid

Comment: Are your color numbers going to be in limited range or they can be arbitrary large (say, total 3 different colors, numbers are 1, 1000, 1000000)?

Comment: @user3787930: You can start with an empty vector, or you can start with any number of elements you want. You can add or remove elements on demand.

Comment: @user3787930 _"first thing that happened is that the size of the vector is declared! ..."_ Just use [`std::vector<int>::push_back()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) if you don't know the number of incoming numbers in advance. Seeing that you're mentioning _"... unique numbers ..."_ points for having a look to [`std::set<int>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) also.

Comment: @Anton Savin The colours will be limited, if there were 3 unique colours the maximum number would be 3. For every new colour, the number increments by 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `vector<vector<int>>` to represent your counters. No maps or sorting are needed.

EDIT: added additional pass to determine maximum color, so no run-time resize is needed.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    int grid[] = { 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, /*...*/};
    const size_t gridSize = std::end(grid) - std::begin(grid);
    int maxColor = *std::max_element(std::begin(grid), std::end(grid));
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> colorPos(maxColor);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < gridSize; ++i)
        colorPos[grid[i] - 1].push_back(i);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < colorPos.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << (i + 1) << ": ";
        for (int p : colorPos[i])
            std::cout << p << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
1: 0 1 8 9 10 17
2: 2 3 4 5 6 7 14 15 22 30
3: 11 12 13 19 20 28
4: 16 24 32 33 40 48 56
5: 18 25 26 27 34 35 36 44
6: 21 23 29 31 37 38 39
7: 41 42 49 50 57 58 59 60
8: 43 45 46 47 51 52 53 54 55 61 62 63
```

Comment: Where can I find more info on how to use those end and begin things, what are they called? Do they belong to <algorithm>? Thank you for the code, i'm going to learn it before I use it though.

Comment: @user3787930 No, they belong to <iterator>: [std::begin](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin), [std::end](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end). For arrays they are defined just as `arr` and `arr + N` respectively.

Comment: depending on your compiler, you might need to put a space between the two >'s:  `vector<vector<int> >`

Comment: @AntonSavin What does the colon do in: for (int p : colourPos[i])

Comment: @user3787930 it's [C++11 Range-based for loop](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-ranged-for-loop.html). If you don't have C++11 you can change it to ordinary for loop of your preference.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it would be better to use some associative container as for example `std::unordered_map` or `std::multimap`.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    int grid[] = 
    { 
        1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 
        4, 1, 5, 3, 3, 6, 2, 6, 4, 5, 5, 5, 3, 6, 2, 6, 
        4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 4, 7, 7, 8, 5, 8, 8, 8, 
        4, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 4, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8 
    };

    std::multimap<int, int> m;

    int i = 0;
    for ( int x : grid )
    {
        m.insert( { x, i++ } );
    }

    std::multimap<int, int>::size_type n = m.count( 1 );
    std::cout << "There are " << n << " elements of color 1:";

    auto p = m.equal_range( 1 );

    for ( ; p.first != p.second ; ++p.first )
    {
        std::cout << ' ' << p.first->second;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output

```
There are 6 elements of color 1: 0 1 8 9 10 17
```

Or

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    int grid[] = 
    { 
        1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 
        4, 1, 5, 3, 3, 6, 2, 6, 4, 5, 5, 5, 3, 6, 2, 6, 
        4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 4, 7, 7, 8, 5, 8, 8, 8, 
        4, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 4, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8 
    };

    std::multimap<int, int> m;

    int i = 0;
    for ( int x : grid )
    {
        m.insert( { x, i++ } );
    }

    for ( auto first = m.begin(); first != m.end(); )
    {
        auto n = m.count( first->first );
        std::cout << "There are " << n 
                  << " elements of color " << first->first << ":";

        auto p = m.equal_range( first->first );

        for ( ; p.first != p.second ; ++p.first )
        {
            std::cout << ' ' << p.first->second;
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;

        first = p.first;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

the output is

```
There are 6 elements of color 1: 0 1 8 9 10 17
There are 10 elements of color 2: 2 3 4 5 6 7 14 15 22 30
There are 6 elements of color 3: 11 12 13 19 20 28
There are 7 elements of color 4: 16 24 32 33 40 48 56
There are 8 elements of color 5: 18 25 26 27 34 35 36 44
There are 7 elements of color 6: 21 23 29 31 37 38 39
There are 8 elements of color 7: 41 42 49 50 57 58 59 60
There are 12 elements of color 8: 43 45 46 47 51 52 53 54 55 61 62 63
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd be best off using a counting sort, which is a sorting algorithm that works very well for sorting large groups of simple types with many duplicate values in better than O(n log n) time.  Here's some sample code, annotated for clarity:

```
// set up our grid
int grid_raw[] = { 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 4, 1, 5, 3, 3, 6, 2, 6, 4, 5, 5, 5, 3, 6, 2, 6, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 4, 7, 7, 8, 5, 8, 8, 8, 4, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 4, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8};

// build a vector using our raw list of numbers.  This calls the range constructor:
// (number 3) http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/
// The trick to using sizeof is that I don't have to change anything if my grid's
// size changes (sizeof grid_raw gives the number of bytes in the whole array, and
// sizeof *grid_raw gives the number of bytes in one element, so dividing yields
// the number of elements.
std::vector<int> grid(grid_raw, grid_raw + sizeof grid_raw / sizeof *grid_raw);

// count the number of each color.  std::map is an associative, key --> value
// container that's good for doing this even if you don't know how many colors
// you have, or what the possible values are.  Think of the values in grid as being
// colors, not numbers, i.e. ++buckets[RED], ++buckets[GREEN], etc...
// if no bucket exists for a particular color yet, then it starts at zero (i.e,
// the first access of buckets[MAUVE] will be 0, but it remembers each increment)
std::map<int, int> buckets;
for (vector<int>::iterator i = grid.begin(); i != grid.end(); ++i)
    ++buckets[*i];

// build a new sorted vector from buckets, which now contains a count of the number
// of occurrences of each color.  The list will be built in the order of elements
// in buckets, which will default to the numerical order of the colors (but can
// be customized if desired).
vector<int> sorted;
for (map<int, int>::iterator b = buckets.begin(); b != buckets.end(); ++b)
    sorted.insert(sorted.end(), b->second, b->first);

// at this point, sorted = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, ...}
```

[Read more about the Counting Sort (includes example python code)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort)

Here's an [ideone](http://ideone.com/juYiBI) that demonstrates sorting your grid.

I'm not 100% sure this answers your question... but you included sorting in the title, even though you didn't say anything about it in the body of your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not forced to use plain arrays, I can propose a map of colors to a vector of positions:

- the [map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) is an associative container, that for any color key returns a reference
- the referenced used here will be a [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/) (a kind of dynamic array) containing all the positions.

Your input grid contains color codes:

```
typedef int colorcode;   // For readability, to make diff between counts, offsets, and colorcodes
colorcode grid[] = { 1, 1, /* .....input data as above.... */ ,8  };
const size_t gridsize = sizeof(grid) / sizeof(int);
```

You would then define the color map:

```
map<colorcode, vector<int>> colormap;
//      ^^^ key      ^^^ value maintained for the key
```

With this approach, your `color1[..]` would then be replaced by a more dynamic `corlormap[1][..]`.  And it's **very easy** to fill:

```
for (int i = 0; i < gridsize; i++) 
    colormap[grid[i]].push_back(i);  // add the new position to the vector returned for the colormap of the color
```

To verify the result,  you may iterate through  the map, and for each existing value iterate through the positions:

```
for (auto x : colormap) {     // for each color in the map 
    cout << "Color" << x.first << " : ";  // display the color (key)
    for (auto y : x.second)     // and iterate through the vector of position 
        cout << y << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
```

You don't know for sure how many different color codes you have, but you want to store for accodes